# Paging Library with custom DataSource not updating row on Room update

Tags: android, list, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I have been implementing the new [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) with a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView) with an app built on top of the [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/).

The data to fill the list is obtained from the [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) database. In fact, it is fetched from the network, stored on the local database and provided to the list.

In order to provide the necessary data to build the list, I have implemented my own custom [PageKeyedDataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PageKeyedDataSource). Everything works as expected except for one little detail. Once the list is displayed, if any change occurs to the data of a list's row element, it is not automatically updated. So, if for example my list is showing a list of items which have a field *name*, and suddenly, this field is updated in the local Room database for a certain row item, the list does not update the row UI automatically.

This behaviour only happens when using a custom DataSource unlike when the DataSource is obtained automatically from the [DAO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Dao), by returning a [DataSource Factory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/DataSource.Factory) directly. However, I need to implement a custom DataSource.

I know it could be updated by calling the *invalidate()* method on the DataSource to rebuild the updated list. However, if the app is showing 2 lists at a time (half screen each for example), and this item appears in both lists, it would be needed to call *invalidate()* for both lists separately.

I have thought with a solution in which, instead of using an instance of the item's class to fill each [ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder), it uses a [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData) wrapped version of it, to make each row observe for changes on its own item and update that row UI when necessary. Nevertheless, I see some downsides on this approach:

1. A [LifeCycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner) (such as the Fragment containing the RecyclerView for example) must be passed to the [PagedListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter) and then forward it to the ViewHolder in order to observe the LiveData wrapped item.
2. A new observer will be registered for each list's new row, so I do not know at all if it has an excessive computational and memory cost, considering it would be done for every list in the app, which has a lot of lists in it.
3. As the LifeCycleOwner observing the LiveData wrapped item would be, for example, the Fragment containing the RecyclerView, instead of the ViewHolder itself, the observer will be notified every time a change on that item occurs, even if the row containing that item is not even visible at that moment because the list has been scrolled, which seems to me like a waste of resources that could increase the computational cost unnecessarily.

I do not know at all if, even considering those downsides, it could seem like a decent approach or, maybe, if any of you know any other cleaner and better way to manage it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite some time since last checked this question, but for anyone interested, here is the cause of my issue + a [library](https://github.com/Sarquella/LifecycleCells) I made to observe [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData) properly from a [ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder) (to avoid having to use the workaround explained in the question).

My specific issue was due to a bad use of Kotlin's [Data Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html). When using them, it is important to note that (as explained in the docs), the *toString()*, *equals()*, *hashCode()* and *copy()* will only take into account all those properties declared in the class' constructor, ignoring those declared in the class' body. A simple example:

```
data class MyClass1(val prop: Int, val name: String) {}

data class MyClass2(val prop: Int) {
    var name: String = ""
}

fun main() {   
    val a = MyClass1(1, "a")
    val b = MyClass1(1, "b")

    println(a == b) //False :) -> a.name != b.name

    val c = MyClass2(2)
    c.name = "c"
    val d = MyClass2(2)
    d.name = "d"

    println(c == d) //True!! :O -> But c.name != d.name
}
```

This is specially important when implementing the [PagedListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter)'s *DiffCallback*, as if we are in a example's *MyClass2* like scenario, no matter how many times we update the *name* field in our [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) database, as the *DiffCallback*'s *areContentsTheSame()* method is probably always going to return *true*, making the list never update on that change.

---

If the reason explained above is not the reason of your issue, or you just want to be able to observe *LiveData* instances properly from a *ViewHolder*, I developed a small library which provides a *Lifecycle* to any *ViewHolder*, making it able to observe *LiveData* instances the proper way (instead of having to use the workaround explained in the question).

https://github.com/Sarquella/LifecycleCells